# Time date format, Converting no of hours into ISO8601 format

Tags: python, date, time

I have a time  in "no of hours", where '0' refers to 12am, '1 refers to 1pm' and so on until 23 hours. Is there any way to convert these number of hours into  "ISO8601" format.    P.S: I have date in proper format

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: I need to covert.  0->00:00:00 , 1->1:00:00, 2->2:00:00  and so on.    The concatenate it with the date (I have the correct format), which eventually produced the following format.   2016-02-11T08:00:00Z

Comment: 1am comes after 12am.

Comment: Sorry about the typo

Comment: What is the date format that you have currently and from where are you getting these number of hours? Are they part of your date already or are you fetching it from somewhere else?

Comment: They are separate from the date. I have some pre-processed data collected by a client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
import time
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(3600 * x))
```

X could your value from 0 to 12.